# Cast a mocked object using google mock

Tags: unit-testing, casting, googlemock

I'm using google mock framework to perform some unit tests over my code. I have a class named SerialPortManager with the constructor:

```
SerialPortManager(SerialPortFactoryInterface* serialPortFactory,SerialParserInterface* serialParsers[PORT_COUNT]);
```

To perform the tests I have the following test fixture

```
class SerialPortManagerTest: public testing::Test {
protected:
SerialPortManager* manager;
MockSerialPortFactory *portFactory;
SerialParserInterface *parsers[PORT_COUNT];

virtual void SetUp() {
    portFactory = new MockSerialPortFactory();
    for (int i = 0; i < PORT_COUNT; i++) {
        parsers[i] = new MockSerialParser();
    }
    manager = 0;
}
```

Now, on one of my tests I need to set an expectation on one of the mocked SerialParsers. I try to do it as

```
EXPECT_CALL(*parsers[0], GetPendingCommands()).Times(1);
```

But I get

```
 Method 'gmock_GetPendingCommands' could not be resolved
```

¿Is there a way to cast the SerialParserInterface pointer to the mocked type?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by casting the argument of the constructor. I declare the parser array as MockSerialParser *parsers[PORT_COUNT], I instantiate the array objects as MockSerialParser * and then I pass the array to the constructor as manager = new SerialPortManager(portFactory,(SerialParserInterface**)parsers);